# Chrome Css Animations break when Web Audio is playing

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, web-audio-api

In Chrome, when the website audio is playing, the label's css animation on the web form fails, even though the JS to fire the addClass function works. However, as soon as I turn off the audio by clicking the sound bars in the bottom right corner, the animations work as expected.

Why would the audio effect the css animation?

https://www.taliscreative.com/contact/

Comment: Did not go deep but the most likely culprit is the animation of the sound bars. Any chance that you're animating them so fast that you're just blocking any other animation?

Comment: Thanks Dunning Kruger. It's definitely the sound bars. But I'm finding that if the animation is longer than about 20ms then it breaks the rest of the animations. So I actually sped up the animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transition of your sound bars has a duration that might be longer than the "duration" of a frame. This means that every frame you ask for an animation that might take longer than a frame. Things start malfunctioning.

You're already animating them on a "frame-by-frame" basis, so you could just set the sound-bar transition duration to 0s and it'll still look smooth!

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfect. I just removed the transition entirely and it still works just as smooth.